# Updating paginated table after filter applied AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/3noebzgr/1/

Everything works except when I filter by jersey number I cannot update the pagination. So if I filter for jersey numbers 1-3, jersey 1 is on page 1, jersey 2 is on page 2 and jersey 3 is on page 4, leaving page 3 empty. I would like for the table to re-paginate to have the filtered list on one page (or more depending on number of items).
This is my paginate function:

```
$scope.paginate = function(value) {
  var begin, end, index;
  begin = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage;
  end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
  index = $scope.players.indexOf(value);
  return (begin <= index && index < end);
};
```

This is where it is applied:

```
<tr ng-repeat="player in players | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:byRange('Number', minNum.Number, maxNum.Number) | filter:paginate">
        <td>{{ player.Name }}</td>
        <td>{{ player.Number }}</td>
        <td>{{ player.Position }}</td>
        <td>{{ player.Team }}</td>
      </tr>
```

The filters:

```
<select  name="minNum" ng-model="minNum" ng-options="player.Number for player in players | orderBy:'Number'">
            <option value="">All</option>
          </select>
```

and

```
<select name="maxNum" ng-model="maxNum" ng-options="player.Number for player in players | orderBy:'Number'">
          <option value="">All</option>
        </select>
```

I have tried other stack overflow suggestions but none have worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

Rerender $scope.numPerPage to be equal $scope.players.length when maxnumber is clicked so that the num per page will be equal players length. Thanks

```
$scope.paginate = function(value) {
  var begin, end, index;
  begin = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage;
  end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
  index = $scope.players.indexOf(value);

  if ($scope.maxNum !== undefined) {
      $scope.numPerPage = $scope.players.length;
  }

  return (begin <= index && index < end);
};
```

Comment: This works to make everything show on one page but it does so by removing the pagination. Is there a way to keep the pagination but move everything onto the same page or if the filtered list is greater than the 'numPerPage' just re-paginate with the current list?